# How to exchange data between websocket and normal socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, high-availability, failover

I have a web application developed in asp.net/c#.
The web app using a 'Client-Socket-Library' developed in c# to connect with socket server.Attached a [system diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLxy9.png) on how the data communication is working at present and how i plan for propsed new changes.
To describe in simple, the existing server/client communicaiton is happening in normal tcp/ip socket. i would like to introduce a proxy server to exchange data between websocket and normal socket communication.

The socket server is developed in cpp using IOCP communication port. To change this socket server to websocket will cost more and we have users using this socket server.This is our core component.

### The advantages we see with the new approach are:

1. The proxyserver will be loosely coupled component. and requires only for the websocket client.
2. Minimal changes in socket server
3. Failover/HA: We can build Failover/HA logic in proxyserver, and if
   any of the socket server is down it will connect to next available
   socket server.

Can we go with the proposed approach?
Any comments/suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://github.com/kanaka/websockify

Comment: Thank you, i'm new to websockify. Can we use this in production system? Any open source license constraint or any limitations in websockify.If you have comeacross/already used please share your thoughts.

Comment: I have no idea, I have never used it. But it seems to be a well established project with lot of followers, and I have heard good things. License is LGPL 3, so probably you can do some research about its implications and how it affects you https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Comment: Thanks again. Will explore more on this topic.earlier the diagram was included but it was showed the hyperlink included the diagram. If you have any comments please share.